# Array Implementation of Linked List

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

Trying to implement linked list using arrays, list gets created but while printing the array gets messed up and prints garbage values

I have used gdb to debug the issue, the array is properly formed just before printing. As soon as I print the array, it starts printing garbage values.

```
int MAX_SIZE=10;

int *head;
int end = -1;

void appendToList(int value){
    if (end == -1){
        int list[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
        head = list;
        *(head + end + 1) = value;
        end++;
    }
    else
    {
        *(head + end + 1) = value;
        end++;
    }

}

int main(){
    appendToList(1);
    appendToList(8);
    appendToList(3);
    appendToList(4);
    appendToList(5);

    std::cout<< head[0] << "\n";
    std::cout<< head[1] << "\n";
    std::cout<< head[2] << "\n";
    std::cout<< head[3] << "\n";
    std::cout<< head[4] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It should print "1 8 3 4 5".
The output is like "1 8 0 0 42050", but that is wrong.

Comment: `int list[MAX_SIZE] = {0};` gets destructed after going out of scope.

Comment: The `list` array in your function is *local*. Once the scope it's defined in ends, so does the life-time of the `list` array. Any pointer you have to it will become invalid.

Comment: Besides, what you're trying to implement is not a linked list, but an arraylist, i.e. an array which prevents you from exceeding its boundary.

Comment: BTW, `int list[MAX_SIZE] = {0};` initializes only the first element of the array.

Comment: @vahancho No that's wrong, the remaining elements of the array will be initialized as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, really? My small test with MSVC shows, that I am not wrong, at least with this compiler: `int list[5] = { 5 };` initializes an array `{5, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.

Comment: To fix, move the definition of `list` so that it's a global variable like `head`. Then `head` and `list` will have the same lifetime. C++ is not a language where objects remain alive for as long as you can access them. Whenever you program C++ you must consider the lifetime of the objects you are creating, and make sure that you don't try to access objects (usually via a pointer) after they have died

Comment: @vahancho Exactly. You initialised the first element to 5 and rest of the elements to 0. The entire array was initialised, just like Some programmer said.

Comment: @eerorika, not exactly. My point was that expression like this: `int list[MAX_SIZE] = {0};` explicitly initialize only the first element, and not all elements, as the code author assumed, IMO. The rest elements get default constructed values.

Comment: @vahancho not default constructed; but rather value initialised. `int list[MAX_SIZE] = {0};` initialises first element to 0 and rest of the elements to 0. I don't see how that could be other than what OP intended.

Comment: @eerorika, aha, now I see. You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`int list[MAX_SIZE]` is a local variable. It's lifetime extends to the end of the scope where it was declared. In this case, the array does not exist outside of the if-statement.

`head = list` sets the pointer in static storage to point to the local array. Once the array is destroyed (at the end of the if-statement block) the pointer no longer points to an object. It is said to be dangling.

Upon further calls to the function, as well as in `main` the program indirects through the dangling `head` pointer, and the behaviour of the program is undefined. To fix this, you must use an array whose lifetime extends for at least as long as it is being used.

You should always be on your toes when a pointer / reference / iterator has longer lifetime than the object they are pointing to.

---

P.S. Your array appears to have nothing to do with a linked list.

P.P.S The program is ill-formed because `MAX_SIZE` is not a compile time constant expression. The size of an array must be compile time constant. To fix this, declare the variable either `const` or `constexpr`.

Comment: Thank you, got it. It is an implementation of linked list using an array, it simulates a linked list or rather it will when the code is complete.

Comment: @hasnain095 It looks more like an implementation of a stack using an array.